# How can I access all of the inline entities in a custom inline entity form validation?

Tags: 8, entities, forms

I have a registration form with inline participant entities like this:

[image]

I'd like to add a custom validation that prevents duplicate email addresses for the participants. In the example above, the user should not be allowed to create another participant with the email address `foo@example.com`.

The participants entity reference field is using the 'Complex' inline entity form widget.

So far I've tried adding an additional validation via `hook_inline_entity_form_entity_form_alter()` and a callback function in `$entity_form['#element_validate']`. In this case, I can get the participant entity from the open 'create participant' form via `$entity_form['#entity']` in the callback function, but it's unclear how to access the email values of the other participants for comparison.

In a different approach, I added a validation to the entire registration form and tried to get the info from `$form_state->getValue('field_participants')`. In this case, I get something like:

```
array:2 [
  "entities" => array:2 [
    0 => array:2 [
      "delta" => "0"
      "actions" => array:2 [
        "ief_entity_edit" => TranslatableMarkup {#1309 ▶}
        "ief_entity_remove" => TranslatableMarkup {#1310 ▶}
      ]
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
      "delta" => "1"
      "actions" => array:2 [
        "ief_entity_edit" => TranslatableMarkup {#1312 ▶}
        "ief_entity_remove" => TranslatableMarkup {#1313 ▶}
      ]
    ]
  ]
  "form" => array:1 [
    "inline_entity_form" => array:3 [
      "field_mail" => array:1 [
        0 => array:1 [
          "value" => "foo@example.com"
        ]
      ]
      "langcode" => array:1 [▶]
      "actions" => array:2 [▶]
    ]
  ]
]
```

It would seem that the open form email value is at `['form']['inline_entity_form']['field_mail'][0]['value']`, but the other two participant entities in `['entities']` have no easy way to access their email value.